# How to deploy code to IBM Cloud using DevOps approach?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Can somebody bring some light in IBM Cloud deployments tools / platforms whatever?

I am new to it, so I am looking at their docs, watching videos and still i am confused.

What I want to achieve is typical scenario fetch code from repo, build it, test it, deploy it to cloud. I found strategies / platforms how to achieve that and i still can't see differences advantages / disadvantages between them.

So we have:

- toolchain
- cloud foundry
- code engine
- Continuous Delivery (service)
- and maybe something more? :)

I am looking at Cloud Foundry explained video and the guy is saying if you want to do not care about the bottom part like networking, security, containers you can choose deploy using K8S service. Wtf? So from total automatic thing you can now handle something in the cloud foundry by yourself. So for me its total mix of everything together and i don't know now which tool / platform / strategy to use.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: You did not say what you mean with "new to it". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask here on Stack Overflow. You are also mixing concepts like toolchains /  DevOps / Continous Delivery with compute options like Cloud Foundry or Code Engine. Edit your question to focus on one specific issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your requirements.

IBM DevOps/Continuous Delivery/Toolchanis is set of services that can build and deploy your application to given runtime. You can find various tutorials here - https://www.ibm.com/cloud/architecture/courses/toolchain-tutorials. These tutorials shows you various things that you can embed in your build pipelines (like code scanning with CRA, image scanning, signing etc)

These runtimes can be different depending on your requirements:

- CloudFoundry, where you deploy app using a buildpak, but this is rather fading technology, so I wouldn't recommend that
- as docker image in K8s/OpenShift cluster - use this if your organization is planning or already utilizing Docker/Kubernetes/OpenShift. You will need to create K8s/OpenShift cluster first.
- as serverless app, using the [IBM Code Engine](https://cloud.ibm.com/codeengine/overview)

If you are just starting and just want to deploy simple, single app to the Cloud I'd consider using IBM Code Engine and not investigate Toolchains for now. Check basic demo here - [How to deploy source code with IBM Cloud Code Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNx9gTWD6h8)